# Find the minimum among all the possible ways to convert to base 2 a real number in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am using this Matlab function to convert a number `d` in base `10` to base `2`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37488951/convert-a-decimal-number-that-is-not-integer-to-base-4-in-matlab)

```
function s = dec2base_float(d,b,nde)
%DEC2BASE_FLOAT Convert floating point numbers to base B string.
%   DEC2BASE_FLOAT(D,B) returns the representation of D as a string in
%   base B.  D must be a floating point array between 0 and 1.
%
%   DEC2BASE_FLOAT(D,B,N) produces a representation with at least N decimal digits.
%
%   Examples
%       dec2base_float(2/5,4,4) returns '0.1212'
%       dec2base_float(2/5,3,6) returns '0.101211'

%// Get "base power-ed scaled" digits
scale = b.^(-1:-1:-nde);

%// Calculate all possible combinations
P = dec2base(0:b^nde-1,b,nde)-'0';

%// Get the best possible combination ID. Index into P with it and thus get
%// based converted number with it
[~,idx] = min(abs(P*scale(:) - d));
s = ['0.',num2str(P(idx,:),'%0.f')];
```

For example `dec2base_float(3/5,2,10)=0.1001100110`.

This function gives **one** among all the possible ways to express `d` in base `2`. Is there any way to display instead the **minimum** among all the possible ways to express `d` in base `2`?

Comment: What is the "minimum" way? What exactly are you minimizing?

Comment: The minimum value among all the ways to express d in base 2

Comment: You've already said that. Obviously, I didn't understand what you mean. I don't even understand what you mean by "all the possible ways". Could you give us an example with some of the possible ways and which one you want?

Comment: For example 1/2 in base 2 can be written as 0.011111111.... or 0.1000000...  I want to get 0.0111111...because it is the smallest between the two.

Comment: 0.0111111 does not equal 1/2.

Comment: It seems yes, see for example the book by Badev on space filling curve section 7.2

Comment: Not in any meaningful sense within the finite storage space of current computers. If you want to indulge in an academic exercise, I suggest you take it to math.se.

Comment: As beaker says, 1/2 can only be written as 0.011111... if you write infinite amount of 1s. Unfortunately we still do not have infinite memory computers, so no, they are not the same in real life.

Comment: OK, thank you all for your explanations